# Mac blocks older versions of unity

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, magic-leap

Has anyone else run into this issue?[image: Apple error that I am receiving]

I am trying to install and run a 2020 unity version because the newer versions of unity doesn't support Magic Leap for AR, but now Apple wants to block the installation because it can't check it for malware and complains that Unity needs to update it. Does anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: So did you contact the developer? Apple does this as they control the software and the environment, for our benefit.

Comment: Unity is a huge software and organization, contacting literally anyone let alone their developers is a lot easier said than done and I usually wait at least a week for any kind of response. I'll try it but I would like to try and resolve this issue sooner as my deadline is approaching steadily.

Comment: Why don't you use UnityHub for downloads?

Comment: are you installing this via the Hub (does the hub even exist for Mac? :'D )?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get such an error after downloading many versions of Unity from 2019 to 2022 on my m1 MacBook Pro.

Anyway, if you still want to use it this way, you can [check this article about how to open an untrusted app](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/open-a-mac-app-from-an-unidentified-developer-mh40616/mac).